# Why doesn't Plot draw function within prescribed range?

Tags: plotting

I have a function:

```
TheoreticalFunction[x_] = 2 / Pi * ArcSin[x]
```

And trying to plot its derivative:

```
Plot[TheoreticalFunction'[z], {z, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

How to plot this from 0 to 1? Why does Plot function stop drawing about 0.9?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The derivative of your function has a discontinuity for $x=1$.

```
theoreticalFunction[x_] := 2/Pi * ArcSin[x]
D[theoreticalFunction[x], x]

(* Out: 2/(Pi Sqrt[1 - x^2]) *)
```

`Plot` uses internal methods that try to **plot "most" points** within the domain given, removing "outliers". This method detects that your derivative rises to infinity for $x=1$ and clips that region out of the plot, as you can see by asking Plot to specifically mention where clipping has happened:

```
Plot[
  D[theoreticalFunction[x], x], {x, 0.9, 1}, 
  ClippingStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick, Dashed], Evaluated -> True
]
```

[image: clipped plot]

You can force Plot to show all points within the region by using `PlotRange`. Because of the large values involve, let me plot the 10-logarithm of your derivative instead:

```
LogPlot[Evaluate@D[theoreticalFunction[x], x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot[EmpiricalFuntion'[z], {z, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

And you'll see why *Mathematica* automatically truncates your plot.

Perhaps you'd like:

```
Plot[EmpiricalFuntion'[z], {z, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0,1}]
```

Comment: Thanks. Understood I have to change my question.